# How to get rid of this resources file error in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

While getting the string from the resource file, I've mistakenly used `R.id.invalidRegex` instead of `R.string.invalidRegex` and it showed an error and pressed `Alt + Enter` and created a new resource id instead of creating a string id.

Now, the problem is, its not compiling and showing **Failed to compile values file**.

How do I get rid of this error ?

Things I've already tried ,

- Cleaning and rebuilding the project.
- Restarting the Android Studio.
- Deleting the `build` directory and rebuilding the project.

Android Studio version - Arctic Fox | 2020.3.1 Patch 4

Thanks for the answer in advance :)

Comment: Search `R.id.invalidRegex` in your project and remove it. Then, try to deleting `build` directory.

Comment: Still not working :( Any other ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

I've found a file named `ids.xml` inside of my project's values folder which caused this error and **not in R.java** file.

After deleting the **ids.xml** file, now its compiling without any errors.